# Setup Multi website store in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, multistore, multi-website

I am creating the local multi-website in Magento 2, for these, I have followed below steps.

Step 1) Created the 3 different root level Category as shown below image

[image]

Step 2) Created the 3 different stores and assigned categories along with as shown below image

[image]

Step 3) Enabled the Store Code to URLs

[image]

Step 4) Enabled the Currency for above 3 stores like Indian Ruppe, Euro, and US Dollars.

Issues:

1) Store switcher is not showing in the front end.

[image]

2) Even if I enter store switcher manually by adding ?___store=us/?___store=fr the categories are not changing. See below image.

[image]

This is my first multistore website, If I miss any steps to configure multistore website please suggest me.

Comment: Please do re-indexing.

Comment: @DineshRajput Yes, I tried re-indexing, setup:upgrade and setup:static-content:deploy still not working.

Comment: Finally, it's worked after some time, I don't know why? what happened? initially. thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you missed the STORES--> All Stores --> Click on the Store and choose the correct default Category ;)
[image]

Comment: Finally, it's worked after some time, I don't know why? what happened? initially.